# A fresh install of snapd and notepad-plus-plus leads to a failure with "unsupported features: snapd2.43"

Tags: debian, snap

On a fresh *Debian 10* install, I did :

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

but I received the message :

error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Mount snap "notepad-plus-plus" (260) (snap "notepad-plus-plus" assumes unsupported features: snapd2.43 (try to update snapd and refresh the core snap))

Then, a `sudo snap refresh notepad-plus-plus` says it is not installed.

but a `sudo snap refresh --list` returns :

```
snap list
Name                    Version                     Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core18                  20210309                    1997  stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804         3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145   stable    canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes       0.1-52-gb92ac40             1515  stable    canonical✓  -
wine-platform-5-stable  5.0.3                       16    stable    mmtrt       -
wine-platform-runtime   v1.0                        216   stable    mmtrt       -
```

All is looking ok,
and no `apt-get update/upgrade` or `sudo snap refresh` find anything to change.
What's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem.
Try to update snapd and refresh the core snap:

```
sudo snap install core snapd
```

If refresh did not help follow instruction below:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/873243/hello-cannot-locate-the-core-snap-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I receive an error message : "_error: cannot install "core", "snapd": cannot install snapd snap on a model without a base snap yet_"

Comment: It worked, but you have to run the two install separately..

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo snap install core
```

In my case, this was enough.